# I need advice on creating an app for uploading training videos

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development

I just got myself into iOS mobile development. I am creating an iOS app that allows athletes to access in-depth training videos for most sports and network with each other. I've already created the login and register UI for the product. What functionalities do you think I need to consider in order for me to create the video based and the social networking part of the app. What backend do you think is best for this project and how long do you think it would take to get it up and running?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Man i think you are in wrong forum. You need to work on possibilities of your budget. I will suggest go with PHP for backending. Deciding time limit is on what is the scope of your project. That will be decided by you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backend Php will be better to use
To post a video you need simple UI having browse or capture video features
func createRequest (videoname : String!) -> NSURLRequest {

```
    print("Path of video upload is:\(videoname)")


    let param = [
        "key" : "\(self.key)",
        "secret" : "\( self.secret)",
        "package_name" : p_name,
        "video" :"\(videoname)"
    ]
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    let url = NSURL(string: Constants.URL_AppFileUpload)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    //request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey:"video",paths:[videoname], boundary: boundary)
    request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithBoundary(boundary, parameters: param, paths: [videoname], fieldName: "video")
    request.timeoutInterval = 120.0

    return request
}
```

You can post video using multipart form data format as given in above example

you can use this packages to use video features in iOS:
import Foundation
import AVKit
import AssetsLibrary
import AVFoundation